# In the Metroid series, what is Bubble Mountain?

Tags: metroid

In the Metroid series of video games, particularly [*Metroid*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metroid) and [*Super Metroid*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Metroid), the [Norfair](https://metroid.fandom.com/wiki/Norfair) region is known for heated rooms, damaging acid, and rocky terrain. However, in *Super Metroid*, the room known as Bubble Mountain ([speedrunning wiki](https://wiki.supermetroid.run/Bubble_Mountain), [fandom wiki](https://metroid.fandom.com/wiki/Bubble_Mountain)) has a unique appearance. To summarize:

- Bubble Mountain is not a heated room; the [Varia Suit](https://metroid.fandom.com/wiki/Varia_Suit) is not required for traversal
- Instead of dark solid rock, the foreground rocks appear to be large green bubbles of up to one meter in diameter, with red highlights, at varying levels of translucency
- The background is similarly changed from surrounding rooms to show more green bubbles with red highlights
- A large spire of bubbles rises from one side, bifurcating the room

Moreover, quoting the fandom wiki:

> ...in *Super Metroid*, these bubbles are exclusively found only in "Bubble Mountain", its adjacent rooms, and the nearby Speed Booster's room.

In terms of game design, it is well-known speedrunning folklore that Bubble Mountain is not heated in order to accommodate [sequence breaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_breaking), colloquially known as "hellrunning." However, in terms of Metroid lore, **why is Bubble Mountain different from the rest of Norfair?**

Answers are welcome to incorporate the [blue-bubble shaft](https://metroid.fandom.com/wiki/Blue-bubble_shaft) in *Metroid*, which has a similar appearance and is also in Norfair.

Comment: This was asked by somebody on Twitch watching a *Super Metroid* speedrun. I can provide an answer involving volcanic glass, but maybe there's a better answer. Let me know if this should really be a question about *all* bubble rooms in Norfair and not just Bubble Mountain.

Comment: In the original game, there were purple bubbles walls too:  https://nesmaps.com/maps/Metroid/MetroidCompleteMap.html